# Epic Games can't login offline

Tags: epic-games-launcher

I'm trying to open Epic Games Launcher without internet connection. Epic asks my email, but it shows

> Sorry the credentials you are using are invalid or have not been stored for offline use.

So, how to make my credential valid for offline use?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official website found [here](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-games-store-c73/launcher-support-c82/how-do-i-run-games-in-offline-mode-using-the-epic-games-launcher-a6724#:%7E:text=%20To%20enter%20Offline%20Mode:%20%201%20Open,Sign%20In%20Later%20at%20the%20bottom.%20More),

> Offline mode is **only** accessible if you don't have an internet
> connection using the Epic Games Launcher. To enter offline mode:
>
> 1. Open the Epic Games Launcher.
> 2. On the Sign-In screen, click on Sign In Later at the bottom.

That's all you have to do to use online mode. Here's a word of advice though. Some games, such as Fortnite, may not function, due to being Internet-dependent.

Comment: Signing in later doesn't allow for some offline games to be played.

Comment: In my case clicking on Sign in Later doesn't do anything. LOL

Answer (score 1):

You would need an internet connection upon the first login. This is because the Launcher can't verify that the account details are correct, as it has no idea what the Epic Games Server has. It would also have no way of knowing what you own without an internet connection.

Basically, sign in with an internet connection, then your credentials will be valid.

Comment: I am prompted every time despite having logged in when last online